# Excel 2010 copying multiple cells on VBA linked sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a work book with 5 identical sheets filtered to different lists

Ive linked these sheets so an edit in 1 sheets updated all the others

Its linked with the following code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
On Error Resume Next
Sheets("NEXT SHEET NAME").Range(Target.Address) = Target
End Sub
```

`NEXT SHEET NAME` = name of next sheet in workbook creating a loop between them

The trouble im having is I can copy paste a single cell but if I try to copy multiple or click and drag to paste in multiple cells it does nothing. It shows hovering over paste but wont actually paste keeping the cells blank.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Comment "On Error Resume Next" with apostrophe out and get the error, then we'll see further.

Comment: Not sure full meaning, I can remove the on error resume next and no errors come up,  I try to paste into more than one cell and it just briefly flashes up then remains blank,  If I unlink the sheets it pastes fine but really I need them linked for a pretty big job soon to start.

Comment: Just found this comment as part of a description for some VBA code 
"If you are not aware, there can only ever be 1 active cell in any selection and that is always the cell you Start your selection from."

Would this mean the code is effectively running change on 1 cell but then as its looping round its basically deleting the cells as blank as part of the loop from matching cells in other sheets.   Sure there must be a way to over come this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing "Value", try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
'On Error Resume Next
  Sheets("NEXT SHEET NAME").Range(Target.Address).Value = Target.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: ill test this now also seem to have just found a solution 


by changing 


Sheets("NEXT SHEET NAME").Range(Target.Address) = Target

to

Sheets("NEXT SHEET NAME").Range(Target.Address) = Target(1,1)

Comment: Ok your method works great thank you for the help,  the trouble with mine was that it copyied the 1st cell only so different data copied didn't work.  Thank you again